# unlisted gsuite apps link no longer work

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a couple of unlisted apps published on the gsuite marketplace, but since today those link give a 400 error:

400. That’s an error.
     The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Last friday they were still working.

The link does work when i use it with my owner account, but all other accounts (private, domain or domainadmin) give a 400 error.

Google, what's wrong?

the link looks like this:

https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/APPNAME/NUMERIC_APP_ID

(actual app info remove, because my unlisted apps are for unlisted for a reason)

Comment: You may refer in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/rPnWFQ2hQRo). One workaround given is to delete and reload browser. If it doesn't work, make sure that your browser is updated. If not, then next, clear your browser cache and cookies and check for bad browser extensions/add-ons.

Comment: it has nothing to do with anything clientside. i've been trying to workaround this issue three days now, somethings wrong with the marketplace. also, they started using the numeric app id instead of the alphanumeric appid, so google seems to be updating some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google seems to have fixed the problem.

the old links work again:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/APPNAME/ALPHANUMERIC_APP_ID

From my marketplace developer account, these are the links used.

thank you Google.